# Determining the case (upper/lower) of the first letter in a string

Tags: javascript, string, uppercase, lowercase

In a web application, how do I determine whether the first letter in a given string is upper- or lower-case using JavaScript?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `toUpperCase`:

```
if(yourString.charAt(0) === yourString.charAt(0).toUpperCase()) {
    //Uppercase!
}
```

If you're going to be using this on a regular basis, I would suggest putting it in a function on the String prototype, something like this:

```
String.prototype.isFirstCapital = function() {
    return this.charAt(0) === this.charAt(0).toUpperCase();   
}
if(yourString.isFirstCapital()) {
    //Uppercase!
}
```

**Update** (based on comments)

I don't know what you actually want to do in the case that the string does not being with a letter, but a simple solution would be to add a quick check to see if it does or not, and return false if not:

```
String.prototype.isFirstCapital = function() {
    return /^[a-z]/i.test(this) && this.charAt(0) === this.charAt(0).toUpperCase();   
}
```

Comment: He did ask for the capitalization of the first letter in a string, which may not be the first character...

Comment: Doesn't work with numbers, @'s, etc :) False positive for all of them. See my answer, however it doesn't consider the @kennebec's note.

Answer (score 1):

This will work only with English alphabet.

```
var ch = myStr.chatAt(0);
if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') {
    // small
} else if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') {
    // capital
} else {
    // not english alphabet char
}
```

Comment: Note that bracket-notation indexes for strings doesn't work in IE 7 and lower - you need to use `charAt()` for compatibility in those browsers.

Comment: Thanks Andy E for noting that. And also James Allardice's answer is far better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

This will be called recursively until a first letter in a string is approached, otherwise returns `'no letters'`.

```
function getFirstCase(string) {
    if (string === '') return 'no letters';

    var firstChar = string.charAt(0);

    /*
     * If both lowercase and uppercase
     * are equal, it is not a letter
     */
    if (firstChar.toLowerCase() === firstChar.toUpperCase()) {
        return getFirstCase(string.substr(1));
    } else {
        return firstChar.toLowerCase() === firstChar ? 'lowercase' : 'uppercase';
    }
}
```

Testing:

```
console.log(getFirstCase('alphabet'), 
            getFirstCase('Sunshine'),
            getFirstCase('123123'),
            getFirstCase('@Hi'),
            getFirstCase('\nHAHA'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var mystring = "Test string";
var first= "";
if (mystring )
{
    first= mystring[1];
}


if (first)
{
    $('p').each(function()
    {
        if ($(this).text().charAt(0).toUpperCase() === $(this).text().charAt(0))
        {
           alert("Uppercase");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised no one's offered a regex solution to this - it seems like the easiest by far:

```
function getFirstCase(s) {
    return (/^[\d\W]*[A-Z]/).test(s) ? 'upper' :
        (/^[\d\W]*[a-z]/).test(s) ? 'lower' :
        'none';
}
```

Blatantly stealing @Lapple's test cases:

```
console.log(getFirstCase('alphabet'), 
            getFirstCase('Sunshine'),
            getFirstCase('123123'),
            getFirstCase('@Hi'),
            getFirstCase('\nHAHA'));

// lower upper none upper upper
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/a5cQa/