# Advanced checking letter case (upper/lower) in string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am working on a special script for fixing letters inside text area. I found one problem where I stack. On Stackoverflow, I could not find a solution for this and need help.

My script has a system for recognition each word what starting with upper first letter and also if a word has all lowercase words. But if I get something like `LoWeRcAsE` my script does not recognize this as an error.

Example:

```
L  - ok
o  - ok
W  - not ok
e  - ok
R  - not ok
c  - ok
A  - not ok
s  - ok
E  - not ok
```

Like you see, first character `L` is ok when is uppercase but also can be ok if is lowercase but any other character in word need to be lowercase.

I try with [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824317/determining-the-case-upper-lower-of-the-first-letter-in-a-string) solution from Stackoverflow but it did not work.

How to do this?

Comment: This seems easy; you could check for `[A-Z][a-z]*` || `[a-z]*` (more or less). (The answer wraps it up into a single, clear regex, but it's the same thing.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex using word boundaries to validate your case:

```
/\b[a-zA-Z][a-z]*\b/
```

This will allow first character to be uppercase or lowercase letter but enforces all other characters to be lowercase letters.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8eKLIp/1)

Comment: This is the most hardest choice. Here I find realy great answers but I choose the most easy one and simple. After almost 5 years how I writting regex by myself I see that I learn over and over. Simple and clean. Thanks @anubhava

Answer (score 1):

I have created this function to check the capitalization of the word. 
You can call this on each word in your text area.

```js
function checkCapitalization(s){
  return (s === s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.slice(1).toLowerCase());
}

checkCapitalization("LoWeRcAsE")
```

Answer (score 1):

not sure how often you need to check specific strings but you could create a method to check the strings like this :

```
String.prototype.isCamelCase = function(){ 
    for( var i=1;i< this.length;i++){
        if( this.charCodeAt(i) < 97) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
} 


"Baz".isCamelCase(); // returns false
"fOo".isCamelCase(); // returns true
```